# resize and crop a image

Tags: php, image, crop

Actually I don't know that there is available any php function to crop and re-size a image with given parameters(x1,y1,x2,y2,width,height) and image name.

I am looking like below function which create new image with given parameters from existing one.

```
 newimg(x1,y1,x2,y2,width,height,image);
```

Currently i have got all above parameters with javascript but now i want to crop image according to above parameters.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/880506

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) can do just that:

> **imagecopyresampled()** copies a rectangular portion of one image to another image, smoothly interpolating pixel values so that, in particular, reducing the size of an image still retains a great deal of clarity.
>
> In other words, **imagecopyresampled()** will take an rectangular area from `src_image` of width `src_w` and height `src_h` at position (`src_x`,`src_y`) and place it in a rectangular area of `dst_image` of width `dst_w` and height `dst_h` at position (`dst_x`,`dst_y`).
>
> If the source and destination coordinates and width and heights differ, appropriate stretching or shrinking of the image fragment will be performed. The coordinates refer to the upper left corner. This function can be used to copy regions within the same image (if `dst_image` is the same as `src_image`) but if the regions overlap the results will be unpredictable.

---

In your case (*untested*):

```
function newimg($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $width, $height, $image) {
    $newimg = ... // Create new image of $width x $height
    imagecopyresampled(
        $newimg, // Destination
        $image, // Source
        0, // Destination, x
        0, // Destination, y
        $x1, // Source, x
        $y1, // Source, y
        $width, // Destination, width
        $height, // Destination, height
        $x2 - $x1, // Source, width
        $y2 - $y1 // Source, height
    );

    return $newimg;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main image libraries for PHP are [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). Both can resize and crop images.